# Why does std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator not propagate on container copy construction?

Tags: c++

Why does `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` not propagate on container
copy construction?

[See the Notes section here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/select_on_container_copy_construction)

Allocators do propagate on move construction, so this behavior seems to be inconsistent.

Also, with copy elision, this behavior can be somewhat odd. Depending on whether a copy ctor is elided or not, the constructed object can have different allocators: if the copy is elided, then the object will have the allocator of the source object. But if it's not elided, it will have the default allocator.

Consider:

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

char buffer[64];
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

std::pmr::vector<char> gvec{&pool};

std::pmr::vector<char> gget() {
    return gvec;
}

std::pmr::vector<char> lget() {
    std::pmr::vector<char> lvec{&pool};
    return lvec;
}

int main() {
    printf("default resource:     %p\n", std::pmr::get_default_resource());
    printf("pool:                 %p\n", &pool);
    printf("\n");

    printf("global copy resource: %p\n", gget().get_allocator().resource());
    printf("local copy resource:  %p\n", lget().get_allocator().resource());
}
```

In this example, `gget` will return a vector with default resource (even though the copied `gvec` object uses `pool`), while `lget` can return a vector with the `pool` resource (depending on whether the compiler decides to elide the copy ctor or not). On my machine, this is printed:

```
default resource:     0x7f67a5be11e8
pool:                 0x55c5924c00e0

global copy resource: 0x7f67a5be11e8
local copy resource:  0x55c5924c00e0
```

But as far as I understand, it would be perfectly valid if the last line looked like this (i.e., the address of the default resource is printed):

```
local copy resource:  0x7f67a5be11e8
```

Is this a design issue, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: "*while lget can return a vector with the pool resource (depending on whether the compiler decides to elide the copy ctor or not)*" No; it will implicitly move from the local variable. There is no copy to elide; the *move* may be elided, but it would behave the same way if the move happened since moves propagate the allocator.

Comment: @NicolBolas: right, I forgot about this rule. What if `vector` had a deleted move ctor? Would my example be valid then? If yes, I can replace `vector` in my example with a custom, allocator aware type, which has a deleted move ctor.

Comment: "*What if vector had a deleted move ctor?*" Then it wouldn't be copyable either, so you would be unable to return an lvalue.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm not sure I understand. `vector` still had a copy ctor, I would just delete the move ctor, so `vector` still should be copyable. I'd do this so the compiler cannot use the move ctor, it must consider to use the copy ctor (and possibly elide it - so my example would be valid then). Also, my `gget` and `lget` functions returns the `vector` by value, so it's an rvalue. Or did you intend to write rvalue?

Comment: "*I'm not sure I understand. vector still had a copy ctor, I would just delete the move ctor*" *You* don't get to delete parts of `vector`; `vector` does that. And if `T` is copyable but not moveable (which is incoherent, but technically valid), `vector<T>` will be neither moveable nor copyable. The [CopyInsertible concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyInsertable) *requires* MoveInsertible.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Let's forget about `vector` for a moment. Suppose that in my example, instead of `vector`, I used a custom, allocator aware type, which has a deleted move ctor. Would my example be valid then?

Comment: Define "valid". If your type is copyable-but-not-moveable, then it is not a valid "allocator aware type", because allocator-aware containers **must** respect CopyInsertible (and the [other requirements of allocator-aware containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) ). If you're talking about some homegrown incoherent copyable-but-not-moveable type, you'll still get a compile error, because an implicit move is still a *move*, which your type can't do.

Comment: @NicolBolas: but CopyInsertible applies to the elements of the container, not the container itself. But I see in your link that `C(rv)` also should work, so in this sense my example cannot be made valid. Nevertheless, I'm not sure that allocator awareness is a requirement for `polymorphic_allocator`. I mean, I could easily use `polymorphic_allocator` in my homegrown container, which doesn't fullfill the `Container` requirement (except if the standard mandates that polymorphic allocator could only be used in types which fulfill Container).

Comment: "*but CopyInsertible applies to the elements of the container, not the container itself.*" But if an element is not CopyInsertible, the container is not CopyConstructible. That's how the requirement works. My only point is that your "return a copy" example doesn't do copying. Ever. It is either a compile error or performs a move/is elided.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I understand that for Container types that's true, thanks! I'm just saying that if I had a homegrown container (not fulfilling Container), which uses `polymorphic_allocator`, and has its move ctor deleted, then in my example copy ctor would be used (and perhaps elided). I understand that this may be a contrived example, but it seems a "valid" one. And also, what if the language had more possibilities to elide copy ctors? If a new copy elision rule comes up, it may invalidate this design decision around `polymorphic_allocator`.

Comment: In practice, now it seems that I cannot "force" the compiler to only consider copy ctor (and possibly elide it). But the theory is the same. If a copy ctor is elided, then the resuling allocator in the container would be different. It still seems weird, even though I cannot come up with an example where this actually happens. Anyways, I think my question still holds, why the difference is there. But it seems that the comments/code example about copy elision is not relevant as it stands.

Comment: "*it seems a "valid" one*" What is "valid" about that? A type that is copyable but not moveable is incoherent. It doesn't make sense; move is a *form* of copy. Such types break parts of C++, and the only type I've seen that does this (`not_null`) gets broken if you start using it in containers.

Comment: "*has its move ctor deleted, then in my example copy ctor would be used (and perhaps elided).*" No, you will get a [compile error](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6Ye87Wj4a). If the statement `return varname;` exists, and `varname` is a local variable, exactly one of two things will happen. There will be a (possibly elided) **move** from `varname`, or your code will fail to compile if `varname` is of a type which cannot be moved from. Copying will not happen. Ever. It won't even be tested for.

Comment: @NicolBolas: by "valid" I meant well-formed. But yeah, I was just trying hard to come up with some example. It's contrived. But again, it's weird that whether copy elision happens or not determines the allocator in the constructed object. Even if it cannot happen in practice currently. But now I learned that this is just a theoretical thing, so I'm fine if we stop here, thanks for the information!

Comment: Regarding the compile error: it's strange, because `gcc -std=c++17` compiles it (that's what I checked during this conversation), but `gcc -std=c++20` doesn't. Clang doesn't compile it no matter of the version of the standard. I suppose that clang is the correct one here? Has something changed regarding this in C++20? (but this questions are a little bit offtopic here...)

Comment: While C++17 and C++20 both say that overload resolution gets performed twice (once for move, once for copy), if you `= delete` the move constructor, overload resolution still *succeeds* for the move. It's just an invalid call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking into the various standard proposals, I can find no explanation for making polymorphic allocators not propagate the memory resource on copy construction. The [very first proposal (pdf)](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3525.pdf) includes this language, and every version thereafter keeps moving it forward.

However, in searching around for the purpose of the mechanism that prevents this propagation (ie: `select_on_container_copy_construction`), I found this statement on [a now-closed defect](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2402):

> I think the people using stateful allocators will alter the default behaviour of `select_on_container_copy_construction` so that it doesn't propagate, but will return a default-constructed one (to ensure a stateful allocator referring to a stack buffer doesn't leak to a region where the stack buffer has gone).

This tracks with something stated in a section of N3525:

> Type erasure is a powerful technique, but has its own flaws, such as that the allocators can be propagated outside of the scope in which they are valid

So it seems to me that this is done to make it more difficult for users to accidentally have stack-bound `memory_resource` types leave the scope in which they are intended to be used.

---

As for elision, the example you give shows that the circumstance you're concerned about (elision changing the behavior of a copy) pretty much cannot happen:

```
std::pmr::vector<char> lget() {
    std::pmr::vector<char> lvec{&pool};
    return lvec;
}
```

This performs a move. That move may be elided, but if it is not, it will be a move.

Indeed, it is essentially impossible to construct a case where elision is an option *and* `vector` would be copied. There are ways to turn `lvec` into a proper lvalue, but all of them shut off elision.

Comment: Thanks for digging that defect report up! It sheds light on how people think about this issue. However, it still a little bit about a different problem. I agree how it was resolved (as the issue is not about about copy ctor, it shouldn't use the allocator from the string). However it has this from Pablo: "Every constructor except the copy constructor for which an allocator is not provided uses a default-constructed allocator.". Does this imply that the copy ctor shouldn't use default-constructed allocator?

Comment: Regarding "So it seems to me that this is done to make it more difficult for users to accidentally have stack-bound memory_resource types leave the scope in which they are intended to be used.". Yeah, it's a possible explanation. But as far as I understand we still have this problem if move ctor is used. which is a more likely case when a function returns a local variable (just like in my example, if `pool` and `buffer` was local, we have a problem).

Comment: As this approach of copy ctor make the design inconsistent in my opinion, and it doesn't avoid too much potential errors, this argument shouldn't have been the basis of this decision. But (again) maybe I don't see something about this.